# TypeError: in method 'new_Frame', expected argument 2 of type 'int'

Tags: python, user-interface, window, wxpython, frame

```
import wx
class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def _init_ (self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame. __init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(200, 100))
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.CreateStatusBar()

        #setting up the menu

        filemenu = wx.Menu()

        menuAbout = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "About", "information about the use of this program")
        menuExit = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "Exit", "Exit this program")

        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()

        menuBar.Append(filemenu,"File")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, menuAbout)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, menuExit)

        self.Show(True)

    def OnAbout(self,e):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "A small text editor", "About sample     editor", wx.OK)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()

    def OnExit(self,e):
        self.Close(True)
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainWindow(None, "sample editor")
    app.MainLoop()
```

Here is the full traceback:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe "C:/Users/User/Google Drive/order/menubar.py" 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:/Users/User/Google Drive/order/menubar.py", line 39, 
    in <module> frame = MainWindow(None, "sample editor") 
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-3.0-msw\wx_windows.py", line 580, 
    in init windows.Frame_swiginit(self,windows.new_Frame(*args, **kwargs)) 
TypeError: in method 'new_Frame', expected argument 2 of type 'int' 
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Can you show us the full traceback?

Comment: From the docs for [`wx.Frame`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Frame-class.html) the parameters are `__init__(self, parent, id, title, pos, size, style, name)`. You've sent `parent` as the second parameter, when it should be an id (of type `int`).

Comment: Have you really got _init_ with one underscore on each side?

Comment: Moved comment to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check spelling of `__init__` method name. It has only 1 underscore
   instead of 2
2. Check spelling of `wx.Frame.__init__` line. Is has excessive space
3. Check indentation starting from the line `app = wx.App(False)`

After that you code should look as follows:

```
import wx
class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__ (self, parent, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, title=title, size=(200, 100))
        self.control = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE)
        self.CreateStatusBar()

        #setting up the menu

        filemenu = wx.Menu()

        menuAbout = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_ABOUT, "About", "information about the use of this program")
        menuExit = filemenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, "Exit", "Exit this program")

        menuBar = wx.MenuBar()

        menuBar.Append(filemenu,"File")
        self.SetMenuBar(menuBar)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnAbout, menuAbout)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnExit, menuExit)

        self.Show(True)

    def OnAbout(self,e):
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(self, "A small text editor", "About sample     editor", wx.OK)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()

    def OnExit(self,e):
        self.Close(True)

app = wx.App(False)
frame = MainWindow(None, "sample editor")
app.MainLoop()
```